# numpy array subtraction, how come?

Tags: python, numpy

Cannot quite understand why x-y is a matrix?

and what is the difference between the shape of x (4,) and y (4,1), aren't they all treated as vectors?

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> y = x[:,None]
>>> x.shape
(4,)
>>> y.shape
(4, 1)
>>> x
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> y
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
>>> x-y
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2],
       [-2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained well in [the documentation for *numpy broadcasting*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules) -

> **General Broadcasting Rules**
>
> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes element-wise. **It starts with the trailing dimensions, and works its way forward**. Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> 1. they are equal, or
> 2. **one of them is 1**
>
> If these conditions are not met, a `ValueError: frames are not aligned` exception is thrown, indicating that the arrays have incompatible shapes. **The size of the resulting array is the maximum size along each dimension of the input arrays.**
>
> Arrays do not need to have the same number of dimensions. For example, if you have a 256x256x3 array of RGB values, and you want to scale each color in the image by a different value, you can multiply the image by a one-dimensional array with 3 values. Lining up the sizes of the trailing axes of these arrays according to the broadcast rules,

(Emphasis mine)

When operating array of shape `(4,)` with array of shape `(4,1)` , the first one is broadcasted to `(1,4)` (As it starts at the trailing dimension and works its way forward, replacing them by `1` if no value at that dimension, hence `(4,)` becomes `(1,4)` .) and then operating both of them together create an array of shape `(4,4)` .

And the shape `(4,1)` is not treated as vector. It is a 2-D array.

Same would have occured if `x` was `array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])` , an array of shape `(1,4)` -

Example -

```
In [70]: y
Out[70]:
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])

In [71]: x = np.array([x])

In [72]: x
Out[72]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])

In [73]: x - y
Out[73]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2],
       [-2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0]])
```

---

Broadcasting always matches starting at the last dimensions, hence trying something like below throws an error -

```
In [79]: y = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])

In [80]: y.shape
Out[80]: (2, 4)

In [81]: x = np.array([1,2])

In [82]: x.shape
Out[82]: (2,)

In [83]: y - x
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-4abb3bd0a148> in <module>()
----> 1 y - x

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,4) (2,)
```

This is because first it checks the last dimensions of both arrays, one is `4` and the other is `2`, they don't match according to the rules, hence it throws the error. If the shape of `x` was `(2,1)` , it would have worked. Example -

```
In [84]: y - x.reshape((2,1))
Out[84]:
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 2):

> what is the difference between the shape of x (4,) and y (4,1)

`x` is a vector ; you would need 1 index to access it's elements.

`y` is a 2-D array ; you would need 2 indexes to access it's elements.

> Cannot quite understand why x-y is a matrix?

This is because `x` and `y` get broadcasted when you subtract them.

`x - y` becomes :

```
[1 2 3 4          [1 1 1 1

 1 2 3 4           2 2 2 2
            -     
 1 2 3 4           3 3 3 3

 1 2 3 4]          4 4 4 4]
```